# Multiple sub-responses for Wordpress site, related with CSS/JS/images, cause delayed response times in Jmeter

Tags: css, wordpress, jmeter

I've been trying to load test a Wordpress site and I'm seeing many sub-responses under the main sampler response in 'View Result Tree' listener. This is probably resulting in more load time displayed in Jmeter as well. I've tried enabling/disabling the 'Retrieve All Embedded Resources' advanced setting of sampler and it has not made a difference.

I want to see only those samplers which are part of my script in 'View Results Tree'. How can I get rid of sub-responses appearing under those samplers in 'View Results Tree'?

Answer (score 0):

If you are recording, Then you have option to skip files with desired extension in Jmeter. So you can skip *.png files and they wont show up in the recorded script.

In HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder there is a tab called Request Filtering.
So when you run the Jmeter script these request will not show up in the listener.

Comment: Concerned files are already skipped in the recording. Still those are showing up as sub-responses under sampler.

Comment: Under HTTP Request Sampler can you uncheck the follow redirects and try?

Comment: Tried it. Unchecking 'Follow Redirects' under concerned samplers did not make a difference. I can still see sub-responses under sampler in View Result Tree.

Comment: Check "Redirect Automatically" and try.

Comment: Checking 'Redirect Automatically' lowered the Load Time by a sec, but could not stop sub-responses from appearing in 'View Results Tree'.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case you have embedded resources retrieval enabled in the [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults), if this is the case - it impacts all the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers, no matter what you set there.

The question is why do you want to disable it? It makes sense only to disable requests to external domains (like Google, Facebook, etc.) so you would focus only on your application.

Downloading images, scripts, fonts, styles, etc. is what real browsers are doing so your script should be doing this as well. Just make sure to add [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to ensure that the resources are downloaded only once or according to [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) headers

More information: [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses/)

Comment: Disabling retrieval of embedded resources from HTTP Request Defaults could not stop sub-responses from appearing in 'View Results Tree'. I assume this phenomenon has something to do with website being a Wordpress one?